# How to overwrite parameters of a Laravel middleware which already is assigned as a group middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

I have a Laravel middleware which accepts parameters. This middleware is assigned to a group of routes on the group level. I need to overwrite the parameters specifically for a single route inside this group. How do I do this?

If I add `->middleware('my_middleware:new_param')` to the specific route, then the middleware is executed twice: first with the default parameters from the group level, second with the new parameter.

If I add `->withoutMiddleware('my_middleware')->middleware('my_middleware:new_param')` then the middleware is not executed at all.

**Example**

*\App\Http\Kernel:*

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel {
  protected $middleware = [
    ...
  ];

  protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'my_middleware_group' => [
      'my_middlware:default_param',
      ...,
    ],
  ];

  protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'my_middlware' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,
    ...
  ];
}
```

*\App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider:*

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
  public function boot() {
    $this->routes(function () {
      Route::middleware('my_middleware_group')
        ->group(base_path('routes/my_routing_group.php'));
    });
  }
}
```

*routes/my_routing_group.php:*

```
// Neither the following line
Route::get('/my-url', [MyController::class, 'getSomething'])->middleware(['my_middlware:new_param']);
// nor this line works as expected
Route::get('/my-url', [MyController::class, 'getSomething'])->withoutMiddleware('my_middleware')->middleware(['my_middlware:new_param']);
```

Comment: May I ask why the group if for? I'm guessing here that there is a bit different approach for this? if you can please add more details about the middleware group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: One must also repeat the exact parameters in `->withoutMiddleware` which one want not to use. This means

*routes/my_routing_group.php:*

```
Route::get('/my-url', [MyController::class, 'getSomething'])
  ->withoutMiddleware(['my_middlware:default_param'])   // the original parameters must be repeated, too
  ->middleware(['my_middlware:new_param']);
```

does the trick.